# Metaio - 3d model based tracking

Tags: android, augmented-reality, metaio

i am following below link for model based tracking.
    https://dev.metaio.com/creator/tutorials/tutorial-14-3d-tracking-based-on-cad-model/

I am trying to track a .md2 animated model based on another 3d model, which is featured in Metaio but when i set everything and start quick preview, everything will be perfect until model track, once it is tracked and a .md2 model appears on screen, background starts affecting it i mean even after i removed the base model still i can see .md2 model.
Can anyone please suggest me what i am missing.

```
1. Setting up basic thing in Metaio.

http://s8.postimg.org/h1hx4cl4l/Setup_in_Metaio.png

2.. .md2 model appears once base model is tracked.

http://s27.postimg.org/d14qsuv6b/Start_Tracking.png

3.. Model is not tracking continuesly :(

http://s22.postimg.org/snqtg62sh/Object_not_tracking2.png
http://s21.postimg.org/isad196af/Object_not_tracking3.png
```

Comment: i have posted my question in july and still no answers :o please suggest me whats the wrong thing i am doing. i want to achieve something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUmNbNa3RYY but before that i just want to make sure that a simple model based tracking works perfectly then i can move forward. Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying to achieve as [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUmNbNa3RYY) using OpenCV, Later when  dig it to the root i found that it can be done but it'll take lot of time to acheive such a smoothness, tweeking for best Tracking so i have shifted to Metaio which gave me the best results and i have achieved the same output as shown in above link, here are the steps what i did.

```
1. Create 3dMap using Metaio Toolbox in ANdroid/Ipad Device.
2. import it to Metaio Creator.
3. Make your tweeks as you want and upload it to Junaio cloud, you'll be provided with the QRCode, save it.
4. Now you can use Junaio app to scan that QRCode and your Tracking is ON.
```

Happy Tracking.